# An API that would allow posting a wordpress blog on behalf of users?

Tags: web-services, wordpress

Does such a thing exist? I have been searching but so far have come up empty. If not for Wordpress, perhaps a similar api exists for Blogger, etc?

Comment: Why is this tagged as "ruby-on-rails"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wordpress has [XML-RPC api](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support) that allows external application to post to your Wordpress blog. Many apps use this, e.g. official Wordpress blogging app for iPad.

Note: it is by default turned off and you have to enable it in Settings.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're doing, there is also a [REST-based, JSON API for WordPress.COM](http://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/) and [Jetpack](http://jetpack.me)-enabled self-hosted blogs.